# Using own Node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create my own module in node.js that I can use later.

For learning purpose I have created a javaScript class to practice this kind of stuff unfortunately I have no idea how to use it properly.

My class:

```
class Taschenrechner {
 let plus = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 + param2;
  }

 let minus = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 - param2;
  }  

 let mal = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 * param2;
  }

 let geteilt = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 / param2;
  }

 let potenz = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 ** param2;
  }
}
```

So let just say I want to export all these functions so that I can use them like this:

```
let calculator = require("taschenrechner");
calculator.add(4, 4);
```

Something like that... (I'm still a rookie as you can see :D)

The official node modules use something like `.exports` is this something I could/should use for my own code as well?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this to export your class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `class`, you wouldn't use `let` inside of it. That's not how to define a class. However I don't think you really want to use class anyway, because you have to instantiate a class, and there's no need here. Better to just define an object instead.

And yes, you'd just use `module.exports` to make your module. Like this:

```
const Taschenrechner = {
  plus: (param1, param2) => {
    return param1 + param2;
  },
  minus: (param1, param2) => {
    return param1 - param2;
  }
};

module.exports = Taschenrechner;
```

However for loading your module: unless you're actually loading your module through npm, you have to include some sort of path. Like this:

```
let calculator = require("./taschenrechner");
calculator.plus(4, 4);
```

Notice, you don't need the `.js`, that's assumed. but you need to have something like the `./` (that's if it's in the same directory as the script that's calling it). or some equivalent relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 5):

`let` isn't allowed inside `class`. With Babel and ES.next [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) it could be:

```
class Taschenrechner {
  static plus = (param1, param2) => {
   return param1 + param2;
  }
  ...
}
```

In ES6, it could be:

```
class Taschenrechner {}
Taschenrechner.plus = (param1, param2) => {
  return param1 + param2;
}
...
```

`Taschenrechner` acts only as a namespace here. `Taschenrechner` shouldn't be a class because it doesn't use a state or other class traits it could benefit from.

Modules are supposed to act as namespaces in JS. With CommonJS modules it should be:

```
exports.plus = (param1, param2) => {
  return param1 + param2;
};
...
```

With ES modules:

```
export const plus = (param1, param2) => {
  return param1 + param2;
};
...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you require a module just by its name (`require("taschenrechner")`), NodeJS searches the module in `node_modules` directory. Therefore, this is a mechanism for importing NodeJS packages (libraries), private or public, published in the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator).

If you want to do so, see the How to [Publish & Update a Package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) in the NPM docs. In the section [How to Create Node.js Modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) is explained how to define your module.

If you don't want to publish your package, you can always use the `.exports` mechanism to require your module. Just write a path in front of the name of the module (file). If the file is in the same directory, example: `require("./taschenrechner")`